# After downloding mail from MailBee.NET Unread mails in the mailbox also mark as read

Tags: c#, .net, email

After downloading mail from using MailBee.NET library, unread mails in the user'
s mailbox also mark as read. Is there a workaround for this.?

Answer (score 1):

No need to make extra method call (imap.SetMessageFlags) to reset seen messages back to unseen.

Simply set imap.SetSeenForEntireMessages property to false before downloading emails.

Answer (score 0):

Used  map.SetMessageFlags Method. It works

https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/MailBee.ImapMail.Imap.SetMessageFlags_overload_1.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).